# How to release codemirror focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I am using `CodeMirror` in my website and I wonder how I can release the focus on `CodeMirror`? Below is the code.

```
const codeEditor = CodeMirror($('#code')[0], {
    tabMode: 'indent',
    mode: 'text/javascript',
    autofocus: true,
    autoRefresh: true,
});
```

I checked the documentation but I couldn't find any method to release the focus.

Answer (score 3):

Use `editor.display.input.blur()`

DEMO: https://codepen.io/quic5/pen/pqLKPp